# Killing all processes older than x, matching regex

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kill

I'm trying to kill all processes by a regular expression older than x - but no processes are found!

```
dep@srv-05:~$ ps aux | grep sidekiq

dep  6154 65.5  4.8 4652148 3170540 ?     Ssl  10:00  32:35 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [1 of 8 busy] stopping
dep  6172 80.8  4.3 4462376 2897480 ?     Ssl  10:20  23:52 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [8 of 8 busy]
dep  9099 89.9  1.7 2216372 1167664 ?     Ssl  10:48   1:23 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [8 of 8 busy]
dep  9548 86.8  1.6 2624832 1097428 ?     Ssl  10:48   1:16 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [8 of 8 busy]
dep 14196  0.0  0.0  13224  2076 pts/17   S+   10:50   0:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
dep 21933 84.8  4.2 4342940 2792592 ?     Ssl  10:41   7:34 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [8 of 8 busy]
dep 26466 29.5  5.8 5116960 3822876 ?     Ssl  09:07  30:18 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [1 of 8 busy] stopping
dep 27790 64.3  4.8 5074216 3210584 ?     Ssl  09:58  33:34 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [3 of 8 busy] stopping
dep 29695 87.4  3.1 3405204 2094332 ?     Ssl  10:44   4:53 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [7 of 8 busy]
dep 29850  0.2  5.0 4663268 3296372 ?     Ssl  mar02  12:42 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [1 of 8 busy] stopping
dep 29919 87.5  2.7 3207616 1805844 ?     Ssl  10:45   4:35 sidekiq 4.2.6 au [8 of 8 busy]

dep@srv-05:~$ killall -o 24h -r sidekiq.*au.*stopping
sidekiq.*au.*stopping: no process found
```

But it's not working somehow?

**UPDATE**

Removing `-o 24h` does not help:

```
dep@srv-05:~$ killall -r sidekiq.*au.*stopping
sidekiq.*au.*stopping: no process found
```

Comment: `killall -o 24h $(ps aux | grep '$regex' | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: Tried to reproduce, but there was no problem with the regex. The observed problem was that the `-o` option seems to be ignored. Maybe in your case it is mishandled in a different way.

Comment: BTW, this question may be more appropriate on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) site or http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Thanks, however removing the `-o` option entirely doesn't change anything

Comment: Are you sure that *stopping* is a part of the process name?

Comment: Hmm - I think so doing: `killall -r sidekiq.*` doesn't work either: `sidekiq.*: no process found` - using `pkill -9 -f sidekiq` works - however that ones does not handle age

Comment: What does `which killall` say?

Comment: /usr/bin/killall

Comment: `command -v killall`? `killall --version`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/killall` and `killall (PSmisc) 22.20
Copyright (C) 1993-2012 Werner Almesberger and Craig Small

PSmisc comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under
the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the files named COPYING.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [*thing*](https://klashxx.github.io/the-killing-machine) about this.

---

[`killall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html)

Will be the perfect tool when there's **no need to inspect the command args**, only process name is taken in consideration.

> -o, --older-than
>         Match only processes that are older (**started before**) the **time**
>         **specified**.  The time is specified as a float then a unit.  The
>         units are s,m,h,d,w,M,y for seconds, minutes, hours, days,
>         weeks, Months and years respectively.
>
> -r, --regexp
>         Interpret **process name** pattern as an extended regular expression.

[`pkill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html)

Example:

```
pkill -f "sidekiq.*au.*stopping"
```

Solves the problem of *hiding parameters*:

> `-f`  Match the pattern anywhere in the full argument string of the process instead of just the executable name.

But **does not provide** a way to sort processes by elapsed time.

---

#### So ... Let’s build our custom solution.

Let's go back to an old friend [`ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) .

From the **man** page:

> -e              Select all processes.
>
> -o format       user-defined format.

**AIX FORMAT DESCRIPTORS**

> This ps supports AIX format descriptors, which work somewhat like the formatting codes of printf(1) and printf(3).
>    For example, the normal default output can be produced with this:
>     `ps -eo "%p %y %x %c"`
>
> ```
>    CODE   NORMAL   HEADER
>    %C     pcpu     %CPU
>    %G     group    GROUP
>    %P     ppid     PPID
>    %U     user     USER
>    %a     args     COMMAND
>    %c     comm     COMMAND
>    %g     rgroup   RGROUP
>    %n     nice     NI
>    %p     pid      PID
>    %r     pgid     PGID
>    %t     etime    ELAPSED
>    %u     ruser    RUSER
>    %x     time     TIME
>    %y     tty      TTY
>    %z     vsz      VSZ
> ```

First things first, To ***Kill*** a process, we need its `PID`, then get how long has it been running and finally the command name and it's args.

This be accomplished by this format string using the codes mentioned in the table above:

```
ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%a"
```

**NOTE** : It’s important to choose a *complicated* string as separator between our fields `>~<`, we don't want to find the same one inside the command name or the args garbling our data.

---

To process this output let's compose an `awk` oneliner, step by step.

#### How to get processes running for + 24h?

In `ps` man page:

> `etime`  ELAPSED  elapsed time since the process was started, in the form `[[dd-]hh:]mm:ss`

So, **a *dash* char in the second field** means that the program has been running for at least 24  hours.

Example:

```
$ ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%a" | awk -v '$2 ~ /-/' FS='>~<'
  528>~<49-04:37:37>~</sbin/udevd -d
  746>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log800 86400
  747>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log445 86400
  748>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log1447 86400
  749>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log450 86400
 2170>~<49-04:37:14>~</sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
 2204>~<49-04:37:14>~<irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
 2270>~<49-04:37:14>~</usr/sbin/mcelog --daemon
 6892>~<49-04:37:01>~</usr/sbin/snmpd -LS0-6d -Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid
 6920>~<49-04:37:01>~<xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
```

**NOTE**: `FS` is set to the string used in `ps` format: `>~<`

#### Does the command line match our *regexp*?

Last step,  check if the `command` + `args` (`%a`) contains our `regexp`, for this example the *rotatelogs* string.

```
$ ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%a" | awk -v r="rotate.*access.*" '$2 ~ /-/ && $3 ~ r' FS='>~<'
  746>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log800 86400
  747>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log445 86400
  748>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log1447 86400
  749>~<21-08:21:52>~</dummys/apache/bin/rotatelogs -f /logs/access_log450 86400
```

Lets print only the pids.

```
$ ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%a" |\
   awk -v r="rotate.*access.*" '$2 ~ /-/ && $3 ~ r{printf "%d ",$1}' FS='>~<'
  746 747 748 749
```

[`Bash command substituion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)  will make the final trick.

```
$ kill $(ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%a" |\
  awk -v r="rotate.*access.*" '$2 ~ /-/ && $3 ~ r{printf "%d ",$1}' FS='>~<')
```

---

#### For your case

```
kill $(ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%c %a"|\
  gawk -v r="sidekiq.*au.*stopping" '$2~/-/ && $3 ~ r{print $1}' FS='>~<')
```

If you want a *finest* control over `app` and `args` values:

```
kill $(ps -eo "%p>~<%t>~<%c>~<%a"|\
         gawk -v app="sidekiq" -v args="au.*stopping" '$2~/-/ &&  $3 ~ app && $4 ~ args{printf "%d ",$1}' FS='>~<')
```

Comment: In OP's case, **`sidekiq 4.2.6 au [1 of 8 busy] stopping`** seems to be the process name (rather than the command line).

Comment: Yes, but `stopping` is part of the process name. Obviously the `sidekiq` process changes its own name upon startup and later during its lifetime.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I handle the `older than` part?

Comment: On macos it's `killall -m processName*`